# Get alternate character when using Alt+up and down arrow keys in visual studio code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Anyone know how to stop Windows from generating alternate characters such as ╬ when using Alt+up or Alt+down?

Visual Studio Code uses these shortcuts to move selections up or down.  When I do that and release the alt key, I get the unwanted character.

Comment: Solved see: https://superuser.com/questions/668394/how-to-turn-off-alt-numeric-keypad-ascii-symbol-insertion windows visual-studio-code

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add *SOLVED* in any form to the title or to edit the solution into the question. If you have a solution you'd like to share, write an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose; that answer should follow the same quality guidelines that apply to any other answer here. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you don't want to do that, then either wait for someone else to write a proper answer, or delete the question.